# Dozer exclude nested field

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Is it possible to exclude a child of a field? e.g. A field "item" contains another "subItem". How can I exlude the "subItem" being mapped?

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>test.ClassA</class-a>
    <class-b>test.ClassB</class-b>    
    <field-exclude>
        <a>item.subItem</a>
        <b>item.subItem</b>
    </field-exclude>                
</mapping>
```

Thanks for any sugestions.

Comment: This shows some examples with exclusion http://blog.xebia.com/2007/09/24/dozer-mapping/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, but there is a trick. You can define contextual mapping for your Item class:

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>test.ClassA</class-a>
    <class-b>test.ClassB</class-b>    
    <field map-id="itemExcludeSubitem">
        <a>item</a>
        <b>item</b>
    </field>                
</mapping>
<mapping map-id="itemExcludeSubitem">
    <class-a>test.ItemA</class-a>
    <class-b>test.ItemB</class-b>    
    <field-exclude>
        <a>subItem</a>
        <b>subItem</b>
    </field-exclude>                
</mapping>
```